# Winforms for Mono on Mac, Linux and PC (Redux)

Tags: winforms, mono, cross-platform, gtk#

(I asked this question [in another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580/making-a-cwinform-application-cross-platform-should-i-use-air-mono-or-something), and got some interesting responses but I'm not too convinced.)

Is Mono's GtkSharp truly cross-platform? It seems to be Gnome based... how can that work with PC and Mac?

Can someone give me examples of a working Mac/PC/Linux app that is written with a single codebase in Microsoft .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com/xpproducts/xpcore/xpmultiplatform.aspx) is supported on Windows, Linux, Solaris, and Mac OS X. The link includes screenshots on Windows and Linux.

Comment: I sent them an email today asking if they use GTK# and in what capacity. It is cross-platform, that´s for sure.

Comment: They don't use GTK# at all. But they do run on all three and use http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms

Answer (score 2):

Realize this is now an old question, but Banshee fits the bill for being a cross-platform application that uses GTK#.  It runs on Max, Linux and Windows.
http://banshee.fm/download/

Answer (score 1):

The best example of a Gtk# app that runs on both Windows and Linux may be Medsphere's OpenVista.  Granted, its not an app that many people need to run, but it is a very professional, polished, open-source Gtk# application.  It shows how a professional Gtk# app can be written.

http://medsphere.org/community/project/openvista-cis

Answer (score 0):

Gtk# is cross platform.  However the only platform where it looks nice is Linux/BSD running GNOME.  If possible somehow, separate frontend and backend and develop separate user interfaces for Linux, Windows and OS X.  Even wx, which does a really good job in looking okay on all three platforms, has its limits.

Working Mac/PC/Linux app in Gtk#?  Tomboy runs on all three I think.

Comment: Tomboy -- http://www.gnome.org/projects/tomboy/ -- is a Gnome subproject. Do I have Gnome on PC or Mac?

Answer (score 0):

It would be more correct to say that GNOME is GTK-based than it is to say that GTK is GNOME based.  GTK is a toolkit that GNOME sits on top of, and you can get GTK for several platforms, including Windows.  That's how GIMP works on Windows: you install GTK first.

Comment: What does that mean for GTK#?

Comment: GTK# is an implementation of User Interface widgets for .Net.  It uses GTK to realize those widgets.